# shiny red hat enterprise linux 5.8 specific issue

Tags: r, linux, shiny

Is there a known issue with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.8 and shiny install? I have R and shiny code working on multiple PCs and Mac OS. My Linux farm IT/SysAdmin person says the R and shiny packages installed properly (I'm at his mercy for installs.) I can run other R packages he installed.

But when I

runApp()

from a R prompt, the browser fires-up and input widgets and non-reactive things show up, but output from reactive and render blocks do not appear. There are no traceback or error messages in R console.

This behavior is the same for demonstration shiny code from Rstudio.

I can't try URL examples served from shiny-server sites to see if those work because external webpage  browsing is turned off in this system. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running R using SSH remote login? You can create an SSH tunnel which maps the shiny-server port on the remote machine to your local computer, for example `ssh -L 3838:localhost:3838 user@remote_server`, and then open the shiny webpage at `http://localhost:3838/your_shiny_app`.

Comment: Not even to the point where it's over remote. Just a

runApp()

command from an R session within local Linux login. Yet still render and reactive not displaying in browser when it comes up at 127.0.0.1. No shiny-server involved yet (as far as I understand what that means at this point.)

Comment: So you have physical access to the computer, but just cannot install software? And why do you say "external webpage browsing is turned off"?

Comment: Yes. I can't install external packages off internet. But SysAdmin did install very recent R and shiny. So 

library(shiny)

works without complaint. Plus 

runApp()

works without complaint. Just no display of reactive outputs.

By external browsing off, I mean if I enter something as simple as  google.com doesn't work Just intranet URLs work.

Comment: PS SysAdmin says he has tested this on a company Enterprise 5.8 system that does have browser access to internet (versus just intranet) URLs and it still does not show reactive and render outputs. He's working on it. But I was hoping for guidance. Thanks.

Comment: What web browser was used when you run `runApp()`? I wonder if it is because Javascript was disabled in browser settings. After I disabled Javascript in my browser, it has the same behaviour: non reactive content is showing but plot etc is not showing.

Comment: Firefox happened to be default for me. I will double check Javascript setting tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Ah well. Good thought, but doesn't seem to be issue. Javascript was enabled.

Comment: Probably try to see if there are any error messages in the browser's javascript console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My support IT person did not give me full details, but he said he needed to recompile some of the base OS packages and install in a separate location, then upgrade to Firefox 12. It now works.